# rails Active_Shipping Fedex SmartPost Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedex

I'm trying to set up a shipping calculator that includes Fedex smart post, but when i run the request, smart post is not included (even though I'm signed up for it). Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (I don't think I'm including "SmartPostDetail" correctly)

```
require 'active_shipping'
include ActiveMerchant::Shipping
destination = Location.new(country: 'US',
    state: 'CA',
    city: 'Beverly Hills',
    zip: '90210')
origin = Location.new(country: 'US',
    state: 'NC', 
    city: 'Burlington', 
    zip: '27217')
package = Package.new((16),[5, 4, 5],:units => :imperial)

fedex = FedEx.new(:key => 'KEY',
    :password => 'PASSWORD',
    :account => 'ACCOUNT#',
    :login => 'METER#',
    'SmartPostDetail' => {
        'Indicia' => 'PARCEL_SELECT', 
        'AncillaryEndorsement' => 'CARRIER_LEAVE_IF_NO_RESPONSE', 
        'SpecialServices' => 'USPS_DELIVERY_CONFIRMATION', 
        'HubId' => '5281'})

response_fedex = fedex.find_rates(origin, destination, package)
fedex_rates = response_fedex.rates.sort_by(&:price).collect {|rate| [rate.service_name, rate.price]}
```

output:

[["FedEx Ground Home Delivery", xxxx], ["FedEx Express Saver", xxxx], ["FedEx 2 Day", xxxx], ["FedEx 2 Day Am", xxxx], ["FedEx Standard Overnight", xxxx], ["FedEx Priority Overnight", xxxx], ["FedEx First Overnight", xxxx]]

Comment: Have you got a solution for above, i am also missing the surepost in response